# What causes the distortion of image textures

Tags: texturing

The window and door textures in this model are inverted somewhat and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Check if there's a UV map for door and window.

Comment: I believe I was just trying to apply a texture of an image to a plane in both of these instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Mr Zak is correct,

It looks like the door and window need to be UV unwrapped. By default all tris are mapped to the same part of the immage. That is why it looks distorted.

with the object selected:

-hit tab to enter edit mode,

-select all vertices of the door or window (but not both)

-hit u twice to unwrap (multiple options are available after the first u)

good luck